# PHPDoc documentation generator in or out of Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, documentation, phpdoc

I am developing with Eclipse + PDT. I've been adding phpdoc comments into my code,
but actually never generated a resulting documentation in Eclipse. How should I do it - is there some functionality in Eclipse, or doc generation should be done externally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To generate the documentation, you should use [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/), which can be installed as a PEAR package.

Then, you have to call it from command-line ; I've never seen it called from Eclipse PDT, actually.

A great solution is to have a continuous-integration platform (using [phpUnderControl](https://github.com/phpundercontrol), for instance), and integrate to creation of the phpdoc in your build configuration file ; this way, the phpdoc is generated everytime someone commits *(or once a day, or whenever you want ^^ )*.

In Eclipse PDT, you can call "external tools" (see "Run > External Tools" in the menu) ; this would allow you to launch the phpdoc command (like you do from CLI) ; but it definitly is not as user-friendly as what Zend Studio offers -- not the same price either, though ^^

Comment: I've used ant to build my php projects, and usually have a doc target.  Eclipse plays very nice with ant.  Also you run phing from eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Another great tool to generate documentation is [ApiGen](http://apigen.org/). It doesn't need installation with PEAR (but includes it) and it can be used like a standalone package.

Comment: How do we install `ApiGen` for windows? I downloaded the `phar` package but have no clue as how to proceed.

Comment: @SuhailGupta take a look here: https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen

Comment: So I included the path `C:\wamp\www\apigen.phar` into user variable `PATH`and also inside the `System` Path. But it doesn't work! Just prints nothing.

Comment: Try to open an issue here: https://github.com/ApiGen/ApiGen/issues

Comment: I typed the command as `php apigen generate --help` and the output is `Could not open input file: apigen`

Comment: Try with apigen.phar

Comment: Same `Could not open input file: apigen.phar`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a wizard to do this in Zend. Check out this [brief guide](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Studio-Eclipse/creating_a_phpdoc.htm).

Alternatively you can create an external launch configuration to invoke the standard [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/).

1. Select Run->External Tools->External Tools Configurations...
2. In the left hand pane, select Program then the new icon (left-most icon above the pane).
3. In the right hand pane, select the Main tab.
4. Enter generate_doc in the Name: field.
5. Enter the path to the phpdoc cli tool in the Location: field.
6. Enter any required arguments in the Arguments field, e.g. for the current project input ${project_loc}.
7. To run the external configuration, select Run.

To rerun the configuration you have a few choices:

1. Select the External Tools icon from the menu bar [external tools icon http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/icon%5Fext%5Ftools.png"](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/images/icon%5Fext%5Ftools.png") then click generate_doc
2. Select Run->External Tools->generate_doc
3. Hit Alt+R, E, 1 (assuming generate_doc is the first item in the list, otherwise pick the appropriate number)

Comment: Thanks, but I am using regular Eclipse + PDT, apparently there is no such an option.