# Create documentation for PHP code using Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, documentation

I've add block comments to my functions and classes as well using `Eclipse`.
Question is, is there any way to create documentation same like `javadoc`?

`Eclipse` details are :
Eclipse for PHP Developers

Version: Luna Release (4.4.0)

Comment: Well, there is [PHPDoc](http://phpdoc.org) and questions on [how to use PHPDoc in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306047/how-to-use-phpdoc-in-eclipse)

Comment: Check this: [PHPDoc documentation generator in or out of Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184627/phpdoc-documentation-generator-in-or-out-of-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) does pretty much the same thing as Javadoc but for PHP. It can easily be integrated into Eclipse as a run configuration, as explained [here](http://ugeshgali.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/how-to-integrate-phpdocumentor-in.html).

Comment: Second link has expired.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the link.